# two level deep master-details for Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, devexpress, master-detail, xtragrid

I am using Entity Framework and DevExpress 10.5 XtraGrid.
Imagine that we have entities
[image: entity]

So my point is to display them in Form using XtraGrids and master-details.
The Level tree of gridControl should look like this:
[image]

So I have implemented events for MainGrid like this

```
#region gridView1_enents
    private void gridView1_MasterRowEmpty(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowEmptyEventArgs e)
    {
        districts c = (districts)gridView1.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        e.IsEmpty = c.districtparts.Count == 0;
    }

    private void gridView1_MasterRowGetRelationCount(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowGetRelationCountEventArgs e)
    {
        e.RelationCount = 1;
    }

    private void gridView1_MasterRowGetRelationName(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowGetRelationNameEventArgs e)
    {
        e.RelationName = "districtparts";
    }

    private void gridView1_MasterRowGetChildList(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowGetChildListEventArgs e)
    {
        districts c = (districts)gridView1.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        e.ChildList = new BindingSource(c, "districtparts");
    }
    #endregion
```

and that works fine: there is a grid, displaying my districts and I can expand each row and there displays another grid with districtparts
The question is: what should I do to display votecallers. The goal is to have two levels of master-detail hierarchy. That means that districts should have districtparts, and districtparts should have votecallers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q232865.aspx)

And some irrelevant words to meet the requirement of 30 characters =)